# How to include CURL URL with variable in a powershell file?

Tags: powershell, curl, post, http-post

Below is the curl command which I am running in a powershell file, which is not working as it is not picking the variable $APIToken value:

```
$CurlArgument = "-s",
            "-X", "POST",
            "http://J253:${APIToken}@jenkins-abc.xyzcorp.com/job/Web/job/buildWithParameters?token=Testing_Smoke"
$CURLEXE = "E:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\curl.exe"
& $CURLEXE @CurlArgument
```

Please suggest how to correctly write the variable.
Thanks

Comment: Change `${APIToken}` to `$APIToken` or `$($APIToken)`. You can read about variable Expansion [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/variable-expansion-in-strings-and-here-strings/)

Comment: Doesn't work, it gives error:                                                                                     HTTP ERROR 401 Invalid password/token for user: J253                                                  However, if I replace the variable with the real token value, it works.

Comment: `@CurlArgument` is wrong but I assume that is a typo in your post. Store your working argument in variable `$x` and the expanded version in variable `$y` and compare x and y.

Comment: and fwiw - you do know you can use plain Powershell io. curl for this?

Comment: I am not aware, can you suggest how to do this plain powerdhell.io for this?

Comment: I would start with `Invoke-Webrequest "http://J253:$($APIToken)@jenkins-abc.xyzcorp.com/job/Web/job/buildWithParameters?token=Testing_Smoke" -Method Post` but most likely it will require some fiddling.

Comment: When you call the script you've shown, do you have the `$APIToken` variable set?

Answer (score 0):

I will put  Lieven Keersmaekers's comment as an answer for all the future visitors:

`$($APIToken)` works, both for **curl** and for **Invoke-Webrequest**.